# Menu and logo disappeared from the header in WordPress

Tags: wordpress, menu, header, graphical-logo

I am currently creating a website using WordPress, I'm also using the Foton Theme. However, the menu and logo had disappeared while I was trying to customize it. The settings are as follows:
The logo is uploaded however it is not appearing on the header.
[image]

[image: This is the header with no logo and menu]

I have tried to check the settings of the header in each page and also the main controller. However, everything seems to be normal.

Comment: Use the browser developer tools so you can check what actually appears in the header. The logo might be there but just not visible. Or the logo might not be there, in which case you should contact the theme developers. They can fix this.